# Installed Kali linux on vbox vm how to install gpu driver?

Tags: kali-linux, resolution

Hi next semester I've a course that require us to use Kali, so I've installed it on VMbox on my mac. It works, but the screen resolution selections are limited to these https://www.dropbox.com/s/fyv68p78fqj7c2b/Skjermbilde%202017-06-08%2002.40.03.png?dl=0

I've tried some guides on how to fix this online. And it didn't seem to be working. The guide that I've been following:
http://www.note.id.lv/2015/07/Kali-Linux-Screen-Resolution-VirtualBox.html

I figured that it might be driver issue..

I'm currently using an macbook pro 13" /w touchbar bought in 2017.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the VirtualBox Guest Additions? It will help.

Use the Devices option in the Vbox menu as it will install the appropriate version